# calculate closing Stock Quantity,price & value by FIFO

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am using sql server 2008.

i am calculating envetory as FIFO method like in tally.

please go through

http://accountingexplained.com/financial/inventories/fifo-method

i have table as

create table #Stock 
( 
StoreId int,
ProductId int,
Transection_Date Date,
transectionType varchar(20),
Unit numeric(18,2),
UnitCost numeric(18,2)
)

```
insert into #Stock  select 1,201, '2014-03-01', 'Beginning Inventory', 68, 14
insert into #Stock  select 1,201,'2014-03-05', 'Purchase', 140, 15.50
insert into #Stock  select 1,201,'2014-03-09', 'Issue', 94, 0
insert into #Stock  select 1,201,'2014-03-11', 'Purchase', 40, 16
insert into #Stock  select 1,201,'2014-03-16', 'Purchase', 68, 14
insert into #Stock  select 1,201,'2014-03-20', 'Issue', 116, 0 
insert into #Stock  select 1,201,'2014-03-29', 'Issue', 62, 0
```

select * from #Stock
drop table #Stock

i am looking sql function or store procedure  which will accept parameter
fromDate,toDate and sorteId

and display as given format
[image]

Comment: Please explain what you have tried, as it makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Make sure your stock tables handle Purchase and Sales as addition and subtraction and presto....

Comment: @naweez did my answer solve your question?

Comment: as per your calculation is right but i doubt according to FIFO is wrong tomorrow i will let you know

Comment: @naweez according to your link the answer should be 54, $16.5 and $891. Please explain how you say it should come out as 54 16.19354839 874.4516129 as I can't see anything that shows me how this is calculated.

Comment: i have given link for attached excel file please download it. calculated by formula

Comment: @naweez according to your link and image the closing rate should be 16.5. I think you are mistaking the closing rate for the issue cost.

Comment: tomorrow i will send you detail calculation. thanks for prompt reply

Comment: Dear sir plz find the link  of excel file with formula. download the file check the formula.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Vbr4wHnCCZeHJiRzd6Rl91Sm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: dear   Steve Ford  sorry your code is perfact , i was wrong. can you one more faver for  me i need to add three more colunm like ItemCode , StoreId & BeforDate, can you write function for me. i need to supply Date,ItemCode & StoreId. so where condition should come like where itemCode = ItemCode and StoreId=storeId and TransDate< BeforDate

Comment: @naweez if you prefix my name with the "at" sign like I have with your name in this comment, I get notified of any comments that you are directing at me. When you say function do you mean stored procedure or do you just mean using local variables using the DECLARE statement etc? If I have answered your question perfectly then you ought to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Steve Ford, thanks for reply,i have edited question please go through it. i need the stock between two date. it should also display opening stock. if you have any query pleas ask me.

Comment: @Steve Ford , i am waiting for your ans.

Comment: @naweez this looks like a new question to me!

Comment: @stave Ford I tried to add two fields in same table I.e productid & storeid but it's not working.  Can you write store procudure or function which will accept two date  & storeid

Comment: @naweez, you probably don't need this anymore, but I was able to use the answer to your question to then make it work for multiple products, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57903115/1626443

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
--DROP TABLE #Stock
create table #Stock 
( 
Transection_Date Date,
transectionType varchar(20),
Unit numeric(18,2),
UnitCost numeric(18,2)
)

--Mar 1 Beginning Inventory 68 units @ $15.00 per unit 
--5 Purchase 140 units @ $15.50 per unit 
--9 Sale 94 units @ $19.00 per unit 
--11 Purchase 40 units @ $16.00 per unit 
--16 Purchase 78 units @ $16.50 per unit 
--20 Sale 116 units @ $19.50 per unit 
--29 Sale 62 units @ $21.00 per unit 

insert into #Stock  select '2014-03-01', 'Beginning Inventory', 68, 15
insert into #Stock  select '2014-03-05', 'Purchase', 140, 15.50
insert into #Stock  select '2014-03-09', 'Sale', 94, 19
insert into #Stock  select '2014-03-11', 'Purchase', 40, 16
insert into #Stock  select '2014-03-16', 'Purchase', 78, 16.5
insert into #Stock  select '2014-03-20', 'Sale', 116, 19.50 
insert into #Stock  select '2014-03-29', 'Sale', 62, 21.00

;WITH UnitsCTE
AS
(
-- GET Total Units Left
    SELECT SUM(
            CASE transectionType 
            WHEN 'Purchase' Then Unit 
            When 'Sale' THEN Unit * -1 
            ELSE Unit END) AS Units
    FROM #Stock
), PurchaseCTE
AS
(
-- Get only purchases in reverse order
    SELECT Unit, UnitCost, Transection_Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Transection_Date DESC ) AS RN
    FROM #Stock
    WHERE transectionType <> 'Sale'
),
UnitCost
AS
(
-- Recursive CTE to get number of units left at each price
    SELECT CASE WHEN Unit > UnitsCTE.Units THEN UnitsCTE.Units ELSE Unit END As Units, UnitCost
    FROM PurchaseCTE 
    CROSS APPLY UnitsCTE
    WHERE RN = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN P1.Unit > (UnitsCTE.Units - (SELECT SUM(Unit) FROM PurchaseCTE P3 WHERE p3.RN < p1.RN))
            THEN    CASE WHEN (UnitsCTE.Units - (SELECT SUM(Unit) FROM PurchaseCTE P3 WHERE p3.RN < p1.RN)) < 0 THEN 0
                        ELSE (UnitsCTE.Units - (SELECT SUM(Unit) FROM PurchaseCTE P3 WHERE p3.RN < p1.RN)) END
            ELSE P1.Unit END,
            P1.UnitCost 
    FROM PurchaseCTE P1
    INNER JOIN PurchaseCTE P2
        ON P1.RN = P2.RN + 1
    CROSS APPLY UnitsCTE
)
SELECT SUM(Units), SUM(UnitCost * Units) / SUM(Units) AS UnitCost, SUM(Units * UnitCost) AS TotalCost
FROM UnitCost
WHERE Units > 0
```