# calculating FIFO inventory opning ,inward,outward & closing Stock in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am using sql server 2008.

i am calculating envetory as FIFO method like in tally.

i have view  which have multiple table output so create sample table as

```
 create table #StockView 
( 
StoreId int, 
ProductId int, 
TranDate Date, 
TransectionType varchar(5), 
Quantity numeric(18,3), 
UnitCost numeric(18,2) 
)
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-03-30 '   ,   'IN'    ,   1870,   35.57   
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-04-05 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   500 ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-04-05 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   150 ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-04-15 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   15  ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-04-23 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   125 ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-04-25 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   40  ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-04-26 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   734 ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-05-15 '   ,   'IN'    ,   1520,   35  
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-05-15 '   ,   'IN'    ,   1520,   35  
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-05-23 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   40  ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-05 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   70  ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-06 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   50  ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-07 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   286 ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-10 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   50  ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-11 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   41  ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-15 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   150 ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-17 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   700 ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-21 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   433 ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-25 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   20  ,   0
insert into #StockView  select  1   ,   512 ,   '2013-06-26 '   ,   'OUT'   ,   25  ,   0

select * from #StockView

StoreId ProductId TranDate  TransectionType Quantity    UnitCost
1   512 2013-03-30                  IN      1870.000    35.57
1   512 2013-04-05                  OUT     500.000     0.00
1   512 2013-04-05                  OUT     150.000     0.00
1   512 2013-04-15                  OUT     15.000      0.00
1   512 2013-04-23                  OUT     125.000     0.00
1   512 2013-04-25                  OUT     40.000      0.00
1   512 2013-04-26                  OUT     734.000     0.00
1   512 2013-05-15                  IN      1520.000    35.00
1   512 2013-05-15                  IN      1520.000    35.00
1   512 2013-05-23                 OUT      40.000      0.00
1   512 2013-06-05                 OUT      70.000      0.00
1   512 2013-06-06                 OUT      50.000      0.00
1   512 2013-06-07                 OUT      286.000     0.00
1   512 2013-06-10                 OUT      50.000      0.00
1   512 2013-06-11                 OUT      41.000      0.00
1   512 2013-06-15                 OUT      150.000     0.00
1   512 2013-06-17                 OUT      700.000     0.00
1   512 2013-06-21                 OUT      433.000     0.00
1   512 2013-06-25                 OUT      20.000      0.00
1   512 2013-06-26                 OUT      25.000      0.00
```

please go through
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/set-based-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-sql-problem/
OR
[calculate closing Stock Quantity,price & value by FIFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777263/calculate-closing-stock-quantity-price-value-by-fifo?noredirect=1#comment43189746_26777263)

above link giving available stock OR Closing Stock and it's value but i am looking store procedure or function which accept store code , product ID , fromDate & End Date and expected out is based on above data is

[image]

opening : data should be come before from date i.e given 1 e.g  @fromDate < 2013-04-01.
inward: between two period total product come i.e  sum(Quantity) 
outward: between two period 
in short i need monthly stock of all product between two period.

please help me i am trying to get this report since more then 6 months

now i almost finished just  i am getting problem in outward Rate. if i get outward Rate  according FIFO then my problem will solve.
i have written store procedure which return opening Qty, Rate & Value.
by this link   https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/set-based-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-sql-problem/.
other is very easy to calculate except outwardRate.

inwardQty =   sum(Quantity)  where transectionType = 'IN' and  TransDate between @startDate and @EndDate

inwardRate =  sum(inwardQty * UnitCost)/ Sum(inwardQty)

inwardValue = sum(inwardQty) * (sum(inwardQty * UnitCost)/ Sum(inwardQty) )

outwardQty = sum(Quantity)  where transectionType = 'Out' and  TransDate between @startDate and @EndDate

outWardRate = ??    -- here i am getting problem, how to get outwardRate occording FIFO method

OutwardValue=  outwardQty *outWardRate

ClosingQty = ( opningQty + inwardQty ) - outwardQty

ClosingRate =  ((OpningValue + InwardValue) - OutwardValue) / (( opningQty + inwardQty ) - outwardQty)

ClosingValue = (OpningValue + InwardValue) - OutwardValue

Comment: How did you classify `Opning` because there no such entry in table and why inward is zero for `2014-04-01 to 2014-04-30` it has `IN` entry

Comment: thanks for reply, befor april march closing data come to in april opning. if check data in april nothing inward product thats why it is zero. i have edit image , i calculated March & April data plz check it. if you have any query plz ask. and use my name @naweez in starting for your comment so i get intimation.

Answer (score 0):

Getting into inventory control FIFO (or LIFO or whatever method used) is never quite as easy as you might think, regardless of the descend links provided.

You refer to dates you are interested in, such as a range, but opening inventory would have to be computed based on those values, and YOU have to determine what is the opening "price each" while properly reflecting an inventory value.  Consider the following.

```
Jan 1  Begin 20  @ 14.59
Feb 1  Buy   10  @ 17.28
Feb 3  Sell  18  @ 22.79  (selling price)
Mar 1  Buy   25  @ 18.34
Mar 3  Sell   9  @ 24.00
Apr 1  Buy   15  @ 16.95
Apr 3  Sell  12  @ 24.00 
May 1  Buy   10  @ 16.24
```

So you ask  for a report for Mar 1 - Jun 1 for the above inventory item.  The opening inventory is 12 (opening inventory PLUS any purchases LESS sales PRIOR TO March 1).  However, your latest purchase on Feb 1 was 10, but have 12 left.  So what do YOU decide to use for the price value... the Feb 1 which was the most recent? or the Jan 1 opening balance where it was based on the most.  Make a decision and stick to it.  Now, the VALUE of the goods. For a quick report, you could just get away with Qty On Hand * Value selected.  However, from a true accounting reporting perspective to the General Ledger, your value is based on the actual VALUE AT THE TIME something was purchased.  So the value would be 2 remaining at the opening Jan 1 inventory date of 14.59 and 10 qty from Feb 1 @ 17.28.

Having worked with a variety of accounting systems myself going back to 1987, I have found similar approaches applied, but will express my own personal preference of the ones exposed to as it looks like you are looking for an answer to a system you are trying to build based on someone else's work anyhow.  This is a SIMPLIFIED version of the table(s)

Items (generic inventory item, overall description, size, mfg, other standard things)
ItemActivity (handles purchases, sales, returns, inventory adjustments that would be per item/store)
ItemSerials (a child level to itemActivity entry IF such items are serialized so they can explicitly be removed from inventory counts when sold and taken out of inventory)

Now, in the ItemActivity - Again, abbreviated (very similar to what you have except QtyAvail)

```
ID,  StoreID, ItemID, TransType, ActivityDate, Qty, Price, QtyAvail
```

The key piece here is the QtyAvail and is only based on purchased quantities of an item.  When items are sold, the system should go to the row for the store/item and (FIFO), FIRST ENTRY available as a purchase that has QtyAvail > 0 and starts applying those from each respective row until the counts are all used up.  If the Qty of most recent sale exceeds those of QtyAvail, you need to reduce the count of the one entry, then look for the next QtyAvail in the list until all sold quantities are accounted for.

So, like the sample scenario for opening balance that might span 2 (or more) untouched purchase inventory counts that makes an opening balance, you could have similar multiple purchased lots of goods NOT sold for your remaining balance as of a given date/time.  So that too... what is the price and value vs on-the-books value.

For a quick review by a warehouse manager, they probably want how many and latest price, great.  However, the true accounting bean-counters want the true VALUE based on how many AT the respective purchased prices to the company and they are completely different numbers... Similarly is applicable to COST-OF-GOODs-SOLD calculations.  Manager just cares that you sold X many at Y price.  Accountants have to go the extra level of how many X at the FIFO-based purchase price entry did it cost the company.

Inventory is a big beast to deal with and you DEFINITELY want a descent handle on it for future, not just for a quick answer solution to get a report.

Comment: already i worked so much on this table, now i almost finished just  i am getting problem in outward Rate. if i get outward Rate  according FIFO then my problem will solve.